# how to access database row data stored in javascript object

Tags: javascript, json

my first question. Normally just find out for myself but this is has got me beaten.

After an ajax send request, I used this php code to get all the rows and cols from my db:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM categories";
$result=$conn->query($sql);  
$arr = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);


print_r($arr)
```

gave me this output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [cat_id] => 1 [cat_name] => Friends [checkbox] => checked ) [1] => Array ( [cat_id] => 2 [cat_name] => Favourites [checkbox] => checked ) [2] => Array ( [cat_id] => 3 [cat_name] => Drink [checkbox] => checked ) [3] => Array ( [cat_id] => 4 [cat_name] => Food [checkbox] => checked )
<br>
```

I encoded it using:

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

I then got the data into a js variable using:

```
result = Request.responseText;
var categories = JSON && JSON.parse(result) || $.parseJSON(result);
```

How do I access the rows of data stored in categories? I can only presume the JSON worked as categories is now a type `[Object object]` but I dont know how else to check.

Answer (score 1):

`categories` should be an array. To test this, do

```
console.log(categories.length);
```

This should print the size of the array (number of rows). If this returns the expected result, use a simple `for` loop to iterate over the rows:

```
for (var i = 0, c = categories.length; i < c; ++i) {
    console.log(categories[i].cat_name);
}
```

Or, alternatively, use `Array.forEach` with a callback function:

```
categories.forEach(function(category) {
    console.log(category.cat_id + ' = ' + category.cat_name);
});
```

Comment: Sorted it as per below but thx for the tips and callback function, I will need that  code later.

Answer (score 0):

I woke up this morning and fixed this myself within 15mins, after having spent hours looking at this day before.

```
echo json_encode($result); //wrong variable
```

should be:

```
echo json.encode($arr); // correct variable
```

Note to self: sleep on it!